# How to update a set of pods running in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

What is the preferred way of updating a set of pods (e.g. after making code changes & pushing underlying docker image to docker hub) controlled by a replication controller in kubernetes cluster?

I can see 2 ways:

1. Deleting & re-creating replication controller manually
2. Using `kubectl rolling-update`

With the `rolling-update` I have to change the replication controller name. Since I'm storing replication controller definition in YAML file and not generating it manually, having to change the file to push out a code update seems to bring about bad habits like alternating between 2 names for the replication controller (e.g. controllerA and controllerB) to avoid name conflict.

What is the better way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Update: `kubectl rolling-update` has been deprecated and the replacement command is `kubectl rollout`. Also note that since I wrote the original answer the Deployment resource has been added and is a better choice than ReplicaSets as the rolling update is performed server side instead of by the client.

---

You should use `kubectl rolling-update`. We recently added a feature to do a "simple rolling update" which will update the image in a replication controller without renaming it. It's the last example shown in the `kubectl help rolling-update` output:

```
// Update the pods of frontend by just changing the image, and keeping the old name
$ kubectl rolling-update frontend --image=image:v2
```

This command also supports recovery -- if you cancel your update and restart it later, it will resume from where it left off. Even though it creates a new replication controller behind the scenes, at the end of the update the new replication controller takes the name of the old replication controller so it appears as pure update rather than switching to an entirely new replication controller.

Comment: When you say recently, which release was it included in?

Comment: It's included in 0.16.1 and newer versions of kubectl.

Comment: It is possible to upgrade just one image in a pod?

Comment: If you have the rc file, you change any part of the pod using `kubectl rolling-update -f rc_spec.yaml`. You do still have to change the rc name and one of the selector fields (typically that would be a 'version' or 'deployment' field).


That being said, replication controllers were not originally meant to be long lived objects. The better abstraction for managing a set of pods and updating them over time is [deployments](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/deployments.html), which are currently available as an API extension and will be added to the API proper in a future release.

Comment: In k8s v1.2+ it's recommended to use deployments instead of rc's. A deployment object controls the rolling update. Use just run kubectl apply -f your-apps-deployment.yaml. The command returns in a second or so and the rolling update happens in the background. You can watch it in various ways like running kubectl get po to see new pods coming and old pods going

Comment: Not sure if deployments solve this problem, but I have a use-case where I don't want to have to update the name of the image each time, I just want to use the latest image (e.g. as part of an auto-deploy process). I can't use rolling-update unless the image name changes, it seems (even with `:latest` appended). I can just delete and remake the replication controller to recreate all pods, but this seems non-optimal. Suggestions?

Comment: If it's part of an auto-deploy process, why not just update the image? You could pretty easily do a client-side resolution from `:latest` to a full image hash and use that as the new image name. Since it's automated anyway, you would write the translation code once and then let the machinery continue. Having the full hash would also make it much easier for you to actually see which particular version is currently deployed.

Comment: and if I have only a deployment and no replication controller ?

Comment: A deployment creates a ReplicaSet (the replacement for replication controller) under the covers, so you will still have one. And in a deployment you can still reference the container by hash rather than by a tag.

Comment: `Command "rolling-update" is deprecated, use "rollout" instead`

Answer (score 0):

The best option I've found so far is [Skaffold](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold), which automatically builds the image, pushes it the image registry and updates the corresponding pods/controllers. It can even watch for code changes and rebuild the image as soon as changes are saved with `skaffold dev` command. This only requires adding a simple `skaffold.yaml` that specifies the image on the registry and path to the Kubernetes manifests. This workflow is described in details in the [Getting Started guide](https://skaffold.dev/docs/getting-started/).

Answer (score 0):

`The following explanations are from` [Kubernetes In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617293725)'`s book`

> Deleting & re-creating replication controller **manually**

Doing a rolling update **manually** is *`laborious`* and *`error-prone`*. Depending on the number  of  replicas,  you’d  need  to  run  a  dozen  or  more  commands  in  the  proper order to perform the update process.**Luckily**, Kubernetes allows you to perform the rolling update with a single command.

> Using kubectl **rolling-update**

Instead of performing rolling updates using ReplicationControllers manually, you can have kubectl perform them. Using kubectl to perform the update makes the process much easier, but, this is now an out dated way of updating apps.

Why performing an update like this isn’t as good as it could be is because it’s **imperative**. How Kubernetes is about you  telling  it  the  desired  state  of  the  system  and  having  Kubernetes  achieve  that state on its own, by figuring out the best way to do it.

> Using **Deployments** for updating apps declaratively --THE BEST ALTERNATIVE--

A  Deployment  is  a  higher-level  resource  meant  for  deploying  applications  and updating them declaratively, instead of doing it through a ReplicationController or a ReplicaSet, which are both considered lower-level concepts.

[image]

Using  a  Deployment  instead  of  the  lower-level  constructs  makes  updating  an  app much easier, because you’re defining the desired state through the single Deployment resource and letting Kubernetes take care of the rest.

One more thing, **Rolling  back**  a  rollout  is  possible  because  Deployments.